# using sed to modify all files in a directory and name the outputs accordingly

Tags: bash, sed, rename, echo

I want the sed command to work on all files in a directory and output the result into a new file. If f is val1.txt, the name of the output file should be val1_ended.txt -this is what I am trying to do with echo and sed, but it doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
files= ls *.txt

echo "${files}"

for f in ${files}$

do 

echo $f

sed -n -e 's/Trial End/&/p' $f>`  echo $f | sed 's/.txt$/_ended.txt/g' `

done
```

In my input files, lines are as such:

```
3413476   999.3   549.3  1876.0 32768.0
3413477  1000.7   549.6  1880.0 32768.0
3413478   999.3   551.1  1875.0 32768.0
INPUT   3413485 127
END 3413485     SAMPLES EVENTS  RES   59.84   45.82
MSG 3413491 Trial End   2
MSG 3414099 RECCFG CR 1000 0 0 R
```

While in output, I want all lines where it finds the pattern "Trial End":

```
MSG 3411256 Trial End   1
MSG 3413491 Trial End   2
MSG 3415678 Trial End   3
MSG 3417842 Trial End   4
MSG 3420114 Trial End   5
```

Comment: your syntax is stuck somewhere between windows and bash. First `files=$(ls *.txt)` and it is not a good reference. You can do this in the `for` line as `for f in *.txt`. And for me to make a comment on your sed command, I need to see a few sample lines from your input file and your expected output.

Comment: Wow, does this code snippet and the answers remind me of the [Evolution of a Programmer](http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/The_Evolution_of_a_Programmer.html).  I guess I'm a guru hacker by now!  :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for file in *.txt; do
  grep 'Trial End' "$file" >> "${file%.txt}_ended.txt"
done
```

I'm using `>>` instead of `>` just in case any of the `*_ended.txt` files already exists—`>>` will append to the file rather than truncating and overwriting it.

Another thing about this is it's not very reusable.  If you've already run it once then you'll have `filename_ended.txt` files that *match the pattern* and get processed, and you'll have `filename_ended_ended.txt` files.

You're better off using another extension for these files to prevent this potential hassle in the future (and by the way, extensions don't matter much in the Unix world).

```
for file in *.txt; do grep 'Trial End' "$file" >> "$file.ended"; done
```

Comment: @user2484316, great!  Here on stack exchange, the preferred method of thanks is by [accepting the answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that you found most helpful.  There's a green checkmark to the left of the answer.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about using grep?
Try the following:

```
for f in *.txt; do
out=$(echo ${f} | sed 's/.txt$/_ended.txt/')
grep 'Trial End' $f > $out
done
```

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)

Comment: Also [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943)

Comment: And by the way, I link people to those all the time; nothing personal!  :D  They're just crucial data for script writers.  On another note, you don't need the `g` flag in your `sed` command when you're using an anchored regex.

Comment: Ha, I know, I just grabbed the sed invocation from the original post, I didn't give that part much thought!